# Getting nearest polygons in both sides of polyline with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, measurements

I have polyline shapes representing roads and another shape layer with polygons that are representing buildings. I have to find some way with ArcPy to measure the distance from a point within the polyline road,usually in the middle, to the nearest buildings at both sides of the road. Graphically it would be something like this

[image]

In short, I'd need some way to use a kind of Near tool but with the functionality about measuring in the direction I want to.

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/45581) for identifying if a point on left or right side of a straight line. Also this [tool](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0a4892bd754146e48b87de2352cdf64d) might help?

Comment: Linear Referencing is what I would use, since it has tools like a Near analysis that tells the side of the line a point is on.  However, I am curious to know why you think you need this information.  It seems oddly specific and not very relevant to geocoding.  Understanding why you want to know this could lead in a different direction that solves your real problem better.  Also, is each segment with a point independent of all other segments for determining the side of the line, or do you have to respect the entire zig-zag path for determining the side that your building falls on?

Comment: I'm explaining better: I need to get the two closest shapes to both sides of a road (polyline) from the middle and measure the size between those points in order to finally get an average width. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the way. What I did was to create perpendicular lines (Polylines) to roads and get the intersection (arcpy.Intersect_analysis) with buildings, then I calculate the distance between those points.

[image: Result of the script. Each axis has information about the width and the road that are intersecting with]

Script code is available in https://github.com/manuasir/Arcpy_Roads_Width for anyone that needs it.